# VS2015 linker looking for old, nowhere mentioned files

Tags: c++, svn, linker, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on a project(game engine) which has a solution with 11 projects(VS projects) in it, 10 of which are static libraries (.lib) and one is an executable (.exe). I'm working on in only from 2 computers - the one at home, and the one at work, both using Visual Studio 2015 Community. The one at home works perfectly well, but the one at work has an issue - when I build the solution the linker is always looking for a "corelib.lib" file. That file existed some time ago, but at some point I starting switching too often between release and debug and I made a new convention to ease the pain of compilation time - now my files are called: corelib_vc14_dbg.lib and corelib_vc14_rls.lib (for debug and release respectively). No matter what I do, the linker always looks for this file. I tried cleaning the solution, I tried full clean up of the svn copy, I tried a fresh checkout, I tried moving the svn copy to another location. I tried looking for "corelib.lib" in the directory (multiple times, using Sublime and Notepad++), and I had zero hits. Files like ".sdf", ".suo", ".user" are not versioned. Object files, libraries, executables and so on, are also excluded from the svn, so there can't be any cached values there (if there should be any). What could be causing the problem? Does Visual Studio cache something like that anywhere? And if so - why couldn't I find it anywhere?

Here are the dependencies of the failing project:

```
Debug:
AdditionalDependencies>openal.lib;opengl32.lib;engine_vc14_dbg.lib;corelib_vc14_dbg.lib;glfw_vc14_dbg.lib;glew_vc14_dbg.lib;gorilla_vc14_dbg.lib;jsoncpp_vc14_dbg.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>

Release
<AdditionalDependencies>openal.lib;opengl32.lib;engine_vc14_rls.lib;corelib_vc14_rls.lib;glfw_vc14_rls.lib;glew_vc14_rls.lib;gorilla_vc14_rls.lib;jsoncpp_vc14_rls.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
```

All .lib files are exported correctly with their new names (example: "corelib_vc14_dbg.lib"), but the linker still looks for the old library file "corelib.lib"

Comment: 1. Check the 'Project dependencies' of the project which fails to link. 2. Can you post all `<AdditionalDependencies>` tags inside that `.vcxproj`? 3. Check the "Target name" and "Output file" properties of the project generating the library.

Comment: This project (the failing one) depends on all other projects, but it is the only one that is actually being linked. Files (corelib_vc14_***.lib) are exported correctly, but the linker looks for the old file (corelib.lib).

Comment: I assume you have no `#pragma comment`s anywhere, right?

Comment: None. I'm using boost, which might have those, but I'm quite sure that's not the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. It was somewhere I never expected it to be - when I moved from VS2013 to VS2015 some references to the old projects have been left out and were causing this strange issue. Thankfully I keep my project folders organized, so I looked through everything in the trunk for "vs2013" and found a bunch of occurances, replaced them manually with "vs2015" and everything worked fine :)